# .NET MAUI: remove space for Flyout Icon

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Using Flyouts in .NET MAUI, for each item there is a space next to it for the icon, but I don't want to use an icon. So how do I remove this space?

Here is the AppShell.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="TestApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="{OnPlatform Android=Flyout, iOS=Flyout, MacCatalyst=Locked, Default=Locked}"
    Shell.FlyoutBackdrop="{AppThemeBinding Light=AliceBlue, Dark=DarkGray}"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=PaleTurquoise, Dark=#1f9e1c}"
    FlyoutBackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=#0b1f0b}"
    Shell.FlyoutWidth="250">

    <FlyoutItem Title="Number 1">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Number1}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Number2">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Number2}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak3Xv.png).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Customize the flyout template

Using grid

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="10,5" ColumnDefinitions="*" RowSpacing="20">
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```